# how did the happens-before relation establish on these two threads in android

Tags: android, concurrency, happens-before

Below is sample code examples of a custom App class and MainActivity class code:

```
public class App extends Application {
  private static String TAG = "APP";
  private int i;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
    HandlerThread t = new HandlerThread("init-thread");
    t.start();

    i = -100;

    Handler handler = new Handler(t.getLooper());

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i = 100;
        }
    });

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.MainHandler h = new MainActivity.MainHandler(Looper.getMainLooper(), App.this);
            h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    });
  }

  public int getI() {
    return i;
  }
}
```

And MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static String TAG = "ACT-1";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    App app = (App) getApplication();
    Log.e(TAG, "i: " + app.getI()); //prints 100
  }

  public static class MainHandler extends Handler {
    private Application application;
    public MainHandler(Looper looper, Application app) {
        super(looper);
        this.application = app;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        App app = (App) application;
        Log.e(TAG, "MSG.what: " + msg.what);
        Log.e(TAG, "i: " + app.getI()); //prints 100
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is change the value of "i" to 100 in INIT-THREAD
and from MAIN thread trying to read the value back.

I was expecting the value of  "i" in onResume and handleMessage to be -100 because they are executing in MAIN thread but the Log printed value is actually 100.

In a way I'm trying to reproduce the classic mistake everyone does in regular java programs but android seems to intelligently avoid it.

So i'm interested in understanding how android is achieving the happens-before relation between two threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no happens-before relationship in setting the value of `i` in this program.  The program contains a data race and is in error.

The fact that you've seen it produce some particular result, in a couple of test runs, is no proof of anything at all.   While the behavior of the code is undefined, when you run it, it will do *something*.  On any particular bit of hardware, it may even do that something most of the time.

Quickly looking at the code, I don't see any read-alter-rewrites, so I think that making `i` volatile would make the program correct.  It would not, however, make any of the comment assertions about the value that a particular `Log` statement prints, accurate.

Comment: Actually there is a happens-before relationship because of Android's Handler. Read my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is happens-before spec:

> Chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification defines the happens-before relation on memory operations such as reads and writes of shared variables. The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write operation happens-before the read operation.
>
> 1. The synchronized and volatile constructs, as well as the Thread.start() and Thread.join() methods, can form happens-before
>      relationships. In particular: Each action in a thread happens-before
>      every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.
> 2. An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method
>      entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation
>      is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking
>      happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that
>      monitor.
> 3. A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar
>      memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, but do
>      not entail mutual exclusion locking.
> 4. A call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread.
> 5. All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join on that thread.
>
> reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

I have commented in code to explain:

```
public class App extends Application {
  private static String TAG = "APP";
  private int i;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
    HandlerThread t = new HandlerThread("init-thread");
    t.start();

    i = -100;

    Handler handler = new Handler(t.getLooper());

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // before next line, i == -100
            // because if you look into handler.post,
            // it is using synchronized block to enqueue this Runnable.
            // And when this Runnable is dispatched,
            // it is using synchronized block of the same monitor.
            // So from 2. you can conclude the i = -100; happens-before here.
            i = 100;
        }
    });

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.MainHandler h = new MainActivity.MainHandler(Looper.getMainLooper(), App.this);
            h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    });
  }

  public int getI() {
    return i;
  }
}
```

Until now there is happens-before relationship for i. Later there is no happens-before relationship:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static String TAG = "ACT-1";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    App app = (App) getApplication();
    Log.e(TAG, "i: " + app.getI()); //prints 100
    // happens-before not guaranteed:
    // there is no happens-before operation between background thread that
    // sets i to 100 and main thread here is running.
  }

  public static class MainHandler extends Handler {
    private Application application;
    public MainHandler(Looper looper, Application app) {
        super(looper);
        this.application = app;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        App app = (App) application;
        Log.e(TAG, "MSG.what: " + msg.what);
        Log.e(TAG, "i: " + app.getI()); //prints 100
        // happens-before not guaranteed for the same reason
    }
  }
}
```

According to spec, same as Blake said, the easiest solution fixing race is to change i to volatile. "It would not, however, make any of the comment assertions about the value that a particular Log statement prints, accurate."

Comment: Agree almost completely with @Helin's comments. Handlers are a safe-publication method so, were the "run" method in onCreate to read the value of "i" it would be guaranteed to read "-100".  However, there is, as I said, no happens-before relationship between the setting of "i" in the "run" method and its read in "onResume".  I would need to spend a bit more time to be completely certain about the read in "handleMessage"

Comment: @Blake should not `handler.post` ensure that `i = -100;` happen before itself? I know the code order does not reflect execution order, but doesn't a synchronization event(e.g., locking, handler.post) ensure code before that line happen-before that line?  (I am not very clear here myself).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code works is because the `Handler#post` method enforces happens-before relationship between the main thread and the `init-thread`.

If you look inside the implementation, at some point the `MessageQueue#enqueueMessage` has a synchronized block using `self` as a monitor. The same monitor is used when the MessageQueue (in its own thread) reads and executes the enqueued messages/runnables.